# Performance optimisation in python for loop

Tags: python, optimization, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a CNN, with my custom dataset, which consists of more than 100k images. These are images, named as `{code}-{uuid}.png`, where `{codes}` are different labels for the images and `{uuid}` are unique file identifiers.

Now, I wrote a function to read these images, which is very suboptimal from the performance point of view. The core which is slowing down the function is the double for loop that I use to read the images, parse the code from the file name and save two arrays, one for the images and one for the corresponding labels:

```
    for code in codes:
        for file in glob.glob(f'features/image_dataset/{code}*.png'):
            labels.append(re.findall(f'{code}', file))
            tmp_ary = np.expand_dims(plt.imread(file), axis=0)
            ary = np.append(ary, tmp_ary, axis=0)
```

How can I improve the performances of the loop?

Comment: You shouldn't keep appending to an array, this leads to a lot of reallocations. Store the arrays in a python list and convert to an array in one step, right after the double loop. But it's possible that the bulk of your time is spent doing IO (i.e. in `imread`).

Comment: Is it possible for you to obtain the code-UUID combinations up front? Reading the entire directory every time will be quite expensive, especially if it has 100K+ images in it.

Comment: In fact, adding structure to your file system will help a lot here, since the search will generally be linear. How many unique codes do you have, and approximately how many UUIDs are there for each code? For that matter, what do the codes actually look like? Either way, you are better off splitting it into a hierarchy so that there are no more than a few hundred items in a given directory.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I cannot get the UUID combinations upfront, but actually your comment let me realise that what I need is only the {code}. I think I will regex the file name to extract it, because I know its position (the first two characters). Don't know how much this will influence the performance though. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I did not think about the reallocation caused by append, thanks. But could you please give me an hint on how to store the arrays efficiently in the python list?

Comment: @giotto. `glob.glob(f'features/image_dataset/{code}*.png')` returns a list if I am not mistaken. You can pre-allocate the whole result set before you enter the loop, and enumerate it to know which index to store into.

Comment: I merely meant appending to a list, but @MadPhysicist's suggestion is the optimal one.

Comment: If you could provide more information about your data, I would be happy to provide you with a selectable answer.